# Umbraco 11 - Render images

Tags: umbraco, umbraco9

In my Umbraco 7.15.7 I'm displaying images in the Partial Views Macro Files as follow:

```
figure>
                @if (newsItem.HasValue("articleImg"))   
                {
                    <img src="@Umbraco.Media(newsItem.articleImg.ToString()).Url" class="img-fluid news-img" alt="@newsItem.Last().photoAlt" />
                }
```

(the reason for the .ToString() is after I switched from Obsolete to Media.Picker2 - so since it's string)

In my Umbraco 11.1 I was struggle to display the images. I tried the following and it didn't display the images, but also didn't throw an error, just didn't display the images:

```
<img src="@Umbraco.Media(newsItem.Value<IPublishedContent>("articleImg").ToString()).Url()" class="img-fluid" alt="@Imaging_pagesToList.Last().Value("photoAlt")" />
```

So I tried this one:

```
<img src="newsItem.Value<IPublishedContent>("articleImg").Url()" class="img-fluid" alt="@newsItem.Value("photoAlt")" />
```

And this one also doesn't show any image

I also tried this one (the same as above, just with @ - @newsItem) , and this throw an error: "Argument 3: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object?'":

```
<img src="@newsItem.Value<IPublishedContent>("articleImg").Url()" class="img-fluid" alt="@newsItem.Value("photoAlt")" />
```

So I tried this one:

```
var image = newsItem.Value<IPublishedContent>("articleImg");
<img src="@image.Url()" class="img-fluid" alt="@newsItem.Value("photoAlt")" />
```

And this is finally works! And I don't understand why? (why this works, and why the previous didn't work)

**My question are:**

Why only the last one works?

Why the first two doesn't work?

Is this is the right way to render images in Umbraco 11.1 ?

In the official documentations of Umbraco (9 and up) they suggest to render images as follow:

```
var mediaItem = Umbraco.Media(Guid.Parse("55240594-b265-4fc2-b1c1-feffc5cf9571"));
```

But they hard coding the Guid in their examples.
Not sure how to get the Guid for each node.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check what property editor is used; maybe it's a collection and not a single media. In that case, you will need something like:

```
newsItem.Value<IEnumarable<IPublishedContent>>("articleImg").First().Url()
```